# Cannot find domain in Active Directory

Tags: .net, active-directory

When I login to remote desktop I switch certain domain - USPHC and then enter login and password. I need to find this domain in code. I have written WinForm application to test it. But I cannot find domain with the help of DirectorySearcher class:

```
DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry();
var search = new DirectorySearcher(dir);
search.Filter = "(&(distinguishedName=USPHC))";
```

or with the help of DirectoryEntry class:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
foreach (DirectoryEntry child in de.Children)
{
listBoxDomains.Items.Add(child);
}

private void listBoxDomains_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBoxDomains.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            DirectoryEntry currentDomain = (listBoxDomains.SelectedItem as DirectoryEntry);
            if (currentDomain.Children != null)
            {
                listBoxDomains.Items.Clear();
                foreach (DirectoryEntry de in currentDomain.Children)
                {
                    listBoxDomains.Items.Add(de);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What did you mean by find that domain?

Comment: Whith the help of my WinForm application I try to collect information about the structure of Active Directory. I have written a code, that show me domains, sub domains, all groups, OUs, but I cannot find domain of user, that I logged(I choose it from drop down list "log in to", when I login). This is worrying me, and I try to understand, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that you search criteria is correct and you have permissions to query that domain?

Comment: Do you mean that such situation is possible: I could login using my username/password,user is in USPHC domain, and my user have permissions to query other domains, but have no permissions to query USPHC domain?

Comment: Everything is possible, you can have access to one tree in domain, an can be denied in other. As I look an your search criteria, you are looking to object in domain tree with such distinguished name, are this object exists?